# Visual Studio 2010 Supported Code Models

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm developing an addon for Visual Studio 2010, and for some features I need access to the events provided by the FileCodeModel associated to a project item. So far, this have been tested and works well in C#, VB.Net, and C++ (although each model has its gotchas).

I tried to reuse the same code for F# projects, but it seems there is no support for F# in the code model mechanism. Stepping through the debugger I see that the FileCodeModel property of the corresponding ProjectItem is null.

so my question is, what are the languages with support for the CodeModel mechanism in Visual Studio 2010? does it work with F#? what about Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: The natural google query is "fsharpcodeprovider".  Which takes you here: http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The `CodeModel.Language` property [is documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel.language%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Y0).  It has code examples in **C#, C++, F#, JScript**, and **VB.NET**.

Some members of the CodeModel object [are not supported in every language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Visual Studio.